# clip image results to a ROI in Google Earth Engine

Tags: mapping, clip, google-earth-engine

I have developed a time series of sea surface temperatures for a specific region of interest in Google Earth Engine. Running the code below displays the sea surface temperatures from the entire data set

```js
Map.addLayer(BIOT)

// Load an image.
var sst = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI').select('sst')
  .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2018-01-01')
  .filterBounds(BIOT);

print('sst', sst)

var TS1 = Chart.image.series(sst, BIOT,  ee.Reducer.mean(),
1000, 'system:time_start').setOptions({title: 'BIOT SST',vAxis: {title: 'SST 
Celsius'},
});
print(TS1);

Map.setCenter(72.25, -6.8, 7); //lat, long, zoom
Map.addLayer (sst, {'min': 23, 'max': 34, 'palette':"0000ff,32cd32,ffff00,ff8c00,ff0000"});
```

I tried to add the code:

```js
Map.addLayer(sst.clip(BIOT))
```

To clip the data to a region I have already defined (`BIOT`) but the image still displays all the data for all regions, rather than the one I have specified. Any ideas? Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sst` is an `ImageCollection`, which can't be clipped this way. This also means, when you execute `Map.addLayer(sst)`, you're mapping all images within the collection, if they are spatially overlapping, they will cover each other up.

If you still want to do that, and you only need the data from your AOI `BIOT` anyways, you can add `.map(function(image){return image.clip(BIOT)})` when you create your `ImageCollection`.

```js
// Load an image **collection**.
var sst = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/OCEANDATA/MODIS-Aqua/L3SMI').select('sst')
  .filterDate('2013-01-01', '2018-01-01')
  .filterBounds(BIOT)
  .map(function(image){return image.clip(BIOT)}) ;
```

This will iterate over each image in the collection and clip it to `BIOT`.

Comment: Yeah that's perfect thanks. I'm pretty new to this and just trying to work a few things out. But that's a real help thank you.